# How to check a dropdown contains any value in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do i check whether a dropdown contains any value at all in jquery?

I have tried..

```
 if(($("#Attribute_1").find(":contains()").length > 0){
        $("#Attribute_1").hide();   
    }
```

dropdown:

```
<select dataid="18" id="Attribute_1" name="Product.Attribute_1">
<option value=""></option>    
<option></option>    
</select>
```

I want the above dropdown to not be displayed because it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the size(), http://api.jquery.com/size/, of the select's children

```
($('#Attribute_1 option').size() == 0) ? $('#Attribute').hide() : $('#Attribute').show();
```

You need to define "empty" though. Is it when you have an empty option tag, or if theres only 1 option tag with no text and/or value?

Or a shorter and better looking way, IMO:

```
$('#Attribute').toggle($('#Attribute_1 option').length);
```

since `0` evaluates to `false`

Comment: I believe this isn't working because the size is two because there are two options

Comment: @Beginner Yes, thats why i asked you to define "empty". Is your example above empty?

Comment: For both, what i mean by empty is if someone clicks on the above dropdown there is nothing they can see in there to select so it is 'empty'. So if there are several empty option tags or several tags with no text or value

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you want to check whether a `select` element (a "dropdown") contains any `option` elements. If that's right just check the `length` of the set of `option` elements:

```
if($("#Attribute_1 option").length) {
    //There are options
}
```

**Update** (see updated question)

You could simply get the `text` of the `select` element. Since the `text` method returns the concatenation of the text content of the element and all its descendants, it will return an empty string when there are empty `option` elements. However, it includes white space so you need to trim the result:

```
if($.trim($("#Attribute_1").text())) {
    //There are options
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the dropdown may have options which are blank